# On the relation for the Myhill-Nerode theorem/syntactic monoid of a language

Tags: fl.formal-languages, algebra, regular-language

In order to characterize regular languages one finds the following definition useful:

> Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet and $L\subseteq\Sigma^*$. Say that $x,y\in\Sigma^*$ are $\equiv_L$-related, and write $x\equiv_L y$ if for all $z\in\Sigma^*$, $xz\in L$ if and only if $yz\in L$.

This is useful because $\equiv_L$ is an equivalence relation for every language $L$, and a language is regular if and only if the index of $\equiv_L$ (that is, the number of equivalence classes) is finite, as per Myhill-Nerode.

Now, I would like to define a binary operation $\cdot$ on $\Sigma^*_{/\equiv_L}$ as: $[x]\cdot[y]=[xy]$, where $[x]$ is the $\equiv_L$-equivalence class of $x$. This $\cdot$ will be operation that will give $\Sigma^*_{/\equiv_L}$ the structure of a monoid.

My question is: Is $\cdot$ well defined for an arbitrary language? How do I prove it?

So far, my approach has been trying to prove that the definition above is equivalent to:

> Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet and $L\subseteq\Sigma^*$. Say that $x,y\in\Sigma^*$ are $\sim_L$-related, and write $x\sim_L y$ if for all $w,z\in\Sigma^*$, $wxz\in L$ if and only if $wyz\in L$.

This is simple for regular languages, since one can take a minimal DFA and analyze its behaviour with strings that are $\sim_L$-related, but I'm struggling with a general proof. Maybe I'm missing something really simple, but in the paper where I found the "definition" of syntactic monoid, they just take $\Sigma_{/\equiv_L}$ and say "this is the monoid" without specifying the operation, and now that I'm trying to do it with full detail I'm completely stuck. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: By well-defined, do you mean $[x] = [y]$ implies, for all class $[z]$ that $[xz] = [yz]$ and $[zx] = [zy]$? This is clear for the first one, but the second one may be false.  The second definition you give (with $\sim$) is the usual one and leads to a "well-defined" monoid.  They are not "equivalent".

Comment: By well-defined I mean it doesn not depend on the representatives that I choose to write the classes. I'm starting to think they are not equivalent (working on an example right now), but in that case, it's a bit surprising that both versions are used indistinctly in different books and papers.

Comment: You may be interested in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/194/compared-growth-of-the-number-of-syntactic-classes-and-nerode-classes BTW.

Comment: Thanks Michaël! So yes, I also found an example that shows they are different relations. I will try to see if the monoid is immediately well-defined when considering $\sim_L$, and maybe I will change the statement of my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntactic monoid of a language $L$, which is $\Sigma^{\ast}$ quotiented by $\sim_{L}$, is usually bigger than the set of equivalence classes of $\Sigma^{\ast}$ quotiented by $\equiv_{L}$. Informally, the Myhill-Nerode relation $\equiv_L$ only cares about the prefixes of a word $w$ (since it reflects the processing of $w$ by a DFA), while the syntactic monoid has to encode the information about all possible infixes of $w$ (otherwise you won't get the algebraic structure $[x]\cdot[y]=[x \cdot y]$)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have yet to prove that $\cdot$ is well-defined, but now I see it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Actually, if $|\Sigma^*/{\equiv_L}| = n$, then $|\Sigma^*/{\sim_L}| \leqslant n^n$, and this upper bound can be reached on a three-letter alphabet.